# Unknown and noisy fields when executing kubectl run and outputting to yaml

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create a pod with dru-run and check it in yaml as follows:

```
k run --restart=Never --image=busybox busybox --dry-run=server -o yaml -- env > mypod.yaml
```

The produced `yaml` file has a ton of fields unknown to me such as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-11-23T15:33:39Z"
  labels:
    run: busybox
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:run: {}
      f:spec:
        f:containers:
          k:{"name":"busybox"}:
            .: {}
            f:args: {}
            f:image: {}
            f:imagePullPolicy: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:resources: {}
            f:terminationMessagePath: {}
            f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
        f:dnsPolicy: {}
        f:enableServiceLinks: {}
        f:restartPolicy: {}
        f:schedulerName: {}
        f:securityContext: {}
        f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
    manager: kubectl-run
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-11-23T15:33:39Z"
  name: busybox
  namespace: mynamespace
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/pods/busybox
  uid: 79e514a9-3c55-4d62-8068-9244252efaa3
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - env
    image: busybox
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: busybox
    resources: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-h57fg
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Never
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - name: default-token-h57fg
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: default-token-h57fg
status:
  phase: Pending
  qosClass: BestEffort
```

Is there a way to avoid these fields being printed out? (and what is their purpose)

working with

```
k version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.0", GitCommit:"e19964183377d0ec2052d1f1fa930c4d7575bd50", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-08-26T14:30:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.0", GitCommit:"e19964183377d0ec2052d1f1fa930c4d7575bd50", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-08-26T14:23:04Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: What fields are you trying to get rid of? The managedFields?

Comment: yes the `managedFields`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**
In Kubernetes 1.21 `managedFields` has been removed from default `kubectl` output.
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/96878
Use `kubectl --show-managed-fields` to display it.

---

That's a new feature called Server-side Apply, enabled by default since Kubernetes 1.18.
It is intended to improve object merge algorithms by tracking fields ownership.

> Server-side Apply works by keeping track of which actor of the system
> has changed each field of an object. It does so by diffing all updates
> to objects, and recording all the fields that have changed as well the
> time of the operation. All this information is stored in the
> managedFields in the metadata of objects. Since objects can have many
> fields, this field can be quite large.
>
> When someone applies, we can then use the information stored within
> managedFields to report relevant conflicts and help the merge
> algorithm to do the right thing.
> https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/04/01/kubernetes-1.18-feature-server-side-apply-beta-2/

A lot of ppl are complaining about noisy output.
Here is the main discussion.
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/90066

For now there is no any suitable way to remove extra fields from the output.

1. You could disable the whole feature.  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/90066#issuecomment-639512202
   But that's not recommended, as it was established for a reason, and new tools and components are likely to rely on a certain behavior it enables.
2. You could use `jq` or `yq` in conjunction with scripts, aliases etc.
   https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/89080#issuecomment-626127959

```html
kyaml() {
  kubectl -o yaml "$@" \
    | yq d - 'items[*].metadata.managedFields' \
    | yq d - '.metadata.managedFields' \
    | yq d - 'items[*].metadata.ownerReferences' \
    | yq d - 'metadata.ownerReferences' \
    | yq d - 'items[*].status' \
    | yq d - 'status'
}
kyaml get pods
```